# Sorting projects in a solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, solution

This ones really an annoyance on my end and searching hasn't resulted in a clear fix yet.

The same .sln file for Visual Studio 2008 is ordering projects in a different way. In my office, I have both my Web Projects at the top and my 3 Websites below (seems to be default alphabetical ordering which is fine!).

At home, same version of VS and SP installed, but one of the Web Projects appears at the bottom of the list. It's just a pain that the order is different, I probably have bit of a personal perfectionist issue going on here but I would expect the same Solution to be ordered in the same way.

I've tried this: http://solutionsorter.codeplex.com

But it bombs out on opening the .sln file.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Jay you can put urls here no need to obfuscate them

Comment: Are the projects pulled from the same source control?

Comment: The sort order of solutions in VS2008 is buggy.  I have filed a bug report on Microsoft connect here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=468874.  Please log in and leave feedback and we have a better chance of it getting fixed :-)

Comment: A bit of extra info, the projects should be ordered alphabetically.  You can force it to sort them alphabetically by doing the following: right click on a project, click rename, cancel renaming the project (don't actually rename the project).  All the projects should now be ordered alphabetically.  The downside is that you need to do it every time you re-open the solution!  It's terribly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but have you ever used Solution Folders to organize your solutions? I have a common ordering that I like my projects to be listed in, so I started creating root solution folders that start with a number, and inside of them I added child solution folders that group each project by a particular kind. For example:

```
1. Clients
   App
   Web
   Lib
   Tst
   Doc
2. API
   Lib
   Tst
   Doc
3. Domain
   Lib
   Tst
   Doc
4. Data Access
   Lib
   Tst
   Doc
5. Framework
   Lib
   Tst
   Doc
```

This works out nicely and keeps large solutions organized, but may be overkill if you only have a few projects in your solution. You might just try the root folders, numbered in the order you preferr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting both of your .suo files? Or how about removing then re-adding.
As far as I know projects should be in alphabetical order.

Edit its in [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=455035) perhaps you should vote it up for vs10

Edit 2:

If you projects are file system Websites the path on you machine may make a difference,

e.g.

If at work you have

```
D:\ThatProject\MyWebsite1
```

and 
    D:\ThatProject\MyWebsite2

and at home you have

```
D:\ThatProject\MyWebsite1
```

and

```
D:\Project\Website2
```

this will cause a different order

Answer (score 0):

Is it being saved in different case on each computer? Sometimes ProjectA is not the same as projectA.

Otherwise, tell us more, we need more clues :)